# Check if file exists for content based routing

Tags: java, apache-camel, predicate

In one camel router, we are check if a flag file exists and only continue if it does. Here is the code we intend to use, but it does not work.

```
String flagFilePath = "file:" + flagFileFolder
        + "?noop=true&idempotent=false&fileName=" + flagFileName;
    from(flagFilePath)
        .choice()
        .when(header("CamelFileName").isNotNull())
            .log(LoggingLevel.TRACE, "Flag file exists.")
        .otherwise()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Flag file does not exist.");
```

I understand that `otherwise` is *not* reachable here because the whole router is not triggered if the files does not exist.

Is there an easy way to check if the file exists without hand-writing Predicates?

(Note: As you can see in the code above, I need this condition to trigger a warning log.)

Comment: Shouldn't you put the flag check outside of the route you want to call and then call the route if the flag file exist?

Comment: See the sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle option

Comment: @ClausIbsen, thanks that solves my problem. Do I need `.endChoice()` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to re-post @ClausIbsen's comments as an answer. The reputation should all go to @ClausIbsen.

Adding `sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true` to the file URI solves my problem.

However, I decided to use a `Predicate` in my code.

```
    from("timer://a-processor?period=" + timerPeriod)
        .routeId("ATimer")
        .choice()
        .when(exchange -> Files.exists(Paths.get(flagFileFolder, flagFileName)))
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Flag file exists.")
        .otherwise()
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Flag file does not exist.")
        .end();
```

I find it more readable and more clear in semantics in my case.